# Running a lot of queries

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models with its methods:

```
class TrendingTopic(models.Model):

    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', through='TTCategory', blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)


    def get_rank(self, t_date=None):
        if t_date:
            ttcs = self.trendingtopiccycle_set.filter(cycle_time__gt=t_date)
        else:
            ttcs = self.trendingtopiccycle_set.all()
        if ttcs:
            return sum([ttc.rank for ttc in ttcs])/len(ttcs)
        return 0

    def get_day_rank(self,t_date):
        ttcs = self.trendingtopiccycle_set.filter(cycle_time__year=t_date.year,
                                            cycle_time__month=t_date.month,
                                            cycle_time__day=t_date.day)
        sum_rank = sum([ttc.day_rank for ttc in ttcs if ttc.day_rank])
        if sum_rank:
            return sum_rank/len(ttcs)
        return 0 


class TrendingTopicCycle(models.Model):

    tt = models.ForeignKey(TrendingTopic)

    cycle_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    from_tt_before = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rank = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    day_rank = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

And then I have some functions that are used in the views to retrieve the desired information:

- Show the best trending topics of the current day:

  ```
  def day_topics(tt_date, limit=10):

      tts = [(ttc.tt, ttc.tt.get_day_rank(tt_date)) for ttc in \
          TrendingTopicCycle.objects.distinct('tt__name') \
          .filter(cycle_time__year=tt_date.year,
                  cycle_time__month=tt_date.month,
                  cycle_time__day=tt_date.day)]
      sorted_tts = sorted(tts, key=itemgetter(1), 
                     reverse=True)[:limit]
      return sorted_tts
  ```
- Show the best trending topics of a given location(woeid) within a determined lapse of time:

  ```
  def hot_topics(woeid=None, limit=10):

      CYCLE_LIMIT = datetime.now() + relativedelta(hours=-5)
      TT_CYCLES_LIMIT = datetime.now() + relativedelta(days=-2)
      if woeid:
          tts = [ttc.tt for ttc in \
                  TrendingTopicCycle.objects.filter(tt__location__woeid=woeid) \
                  .distinct('tt__name') \
                  .exclude(cycle_time__lt=CYCLE_LIMIT)]
      else:
          tts = [ttc.tt for ttc in \
                  TrendingTopicCycle.objects.distinct('tt__name') \
                  .exclude(cycle_time__lt=CYCLE_LIMIT)]


      sorted_tts = sorted(tts, key=lambda tt: tt.get_rank(TT_CYCLES_LIMIT),
                  reverse=True)[:limit]    
      return sorted_tts
  ```

The problem with the current solution is that it runs really slow because its doing a lot of queries(100's) to retrieve the data. I'm using the django debug toolbar to help me measuring the performance.

Obviously I'm doing something terribly wrong and I'm looking for a solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Each trending topic has a set of trending topic cycle(ttc). Each ttc has two ranks: the general one(rank) and the day_rank. The trending topic ranks are calculated looping through each ttc.

Answer (score 1):

First, be aware that django-debug-toolbar, while fantastic, is itself very slow. If you comment out its middleware, your response times improve *dramatically*. It's a very useful tool, don't get me wrong. I use it myself, religiously, but the point is you can't benchmark your site on something subjective like "slowness" while it's enabled.

Second, your code is a little confusing, so it's difficult to say exactly what you should do. For example, `TrendingTopicCycle` has a `rank` and `day_rank` field, but you never use them in the posted code. Calling `get_day_rank` issues a query each time, so it would obviously be more efficient if you could just filter on the `day_rank` field itself (eliminating the need for that query), but I cannot tell from the code you have here if or when those fields are actually set.

A small improvement you can make to the code as is, is judiciously using `select_related`. For instance, each time `ttc.tt.get_day_rank(tt_date))` is run in the list comprehension, a query is issued to get `tt` and then another query is issued in `get_day_rank`. Simply adding `.select_related('tt')` to your queryset would at least eliminate that query for `tt`.

Also, I'm not sure if it actually causes Django to issue a different query or not (and perhaps a more inefficient query), but regardless, there's no point in filtering individually for `year`, `month`, *and* `day`, just filter on the full date, i.e.:

```
TrendingTopicCycle.objects.distinct('tt__name') \
    .filter(cycle_time=date)
```

Comment: I think the year month day is most likely not indexed. You are right though, it would be alot easier to do date searches on a single indexed datetime field.

Comment: Hi Chris, first of all thanks for your response, I'm currently looking for places to use the select_related() method, so I'll try adding it in the queryset. I'm editing the original post to clarify the things you couldn't undertand.

Comment: Another thing, the problem with filtering on the full date is that cycle_time is a datetime field.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can filter a datetime field by a date type. Django works it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ttcs:
            return sum([ttc.rank for ttc in ttcs])/len(ttcs)
        return 0
```

This can be replaced by a db query. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

something like:

```
ttcs.Aggregate(Sum('rank'))["sum__rank"]
```